# Passagem de parâmetros para Modal

Tags: json, angularjs, angular

Estou com problemas ao passar parâmetros para meu Modal, gostaria de apresentar os dados da tupla selecionada, consegui isolar o valor devidamente (atestei pelo console.log), porém, este mesmo não está sendo passado para meu modal, parece que precisaria de algo como uma chamada assíncrona, mesmo que toda operação ocorra dentro de meu front (não faz uma nova chamada do banco).

A intenção é fazer um formulário, porém, apenas para verificar que os dados estão sendo passados devidamente, vou usar a simples passagem do meu JSON, resolvendo isso já estaria ótimo para dar continuidade.

Código do filtro:

```
 filtrardetalhes(value){

     this.planilhaDetalhes = this.planilha.filter(x => 
        x.PID == value
     );
     console.log(this.planilhaDetalhes)

 }
```

Modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" (click)="filtrardetalhes(planilha.PID)">
    Details
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <img src="assets/Detalhes.png" width="25px"/>
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">  Detalhes </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{planilhaDetalhes}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) = "AtualizaBtn()">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Coloquei um "Input" na minha variável "PlanilhaDetalhes" porém apenas para fins de teste:

```
  @Input('planilhaDetalhes') public planilhaDetalhes
```

Como o parâmetro está sendo passado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale ressaltar que o filtro está funcional, apenas deixei meu JSON fechado pois contém informações confidenciais de negócio, porém este JSON de 1 posição é o filtro de um de 74 (e acompanha aonde eu clicar em DETAILS)

EDIT:

Resolvido, passei o JSON na íntegra, porém, estou na dúvida se consigo passar algum parâmetro específico, por exemplo, {{planilhaDetalhes.CAMPO | JSON}}

Segue como ficou a passagem para meu form:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Formulário funcional (sem conseguir passar parâmetros ainda) dentro do BODY do MODAL:

```
   <form class="meuFormulario" [formGroup]="cadastroForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Cliente</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="CLIENTE" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.PID}}"> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">CODIGO DMD</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="CODIGODMD" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.CODIGODMD}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Sigla RM</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="SIGLARM" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.SIGLARM}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Sigla Portal</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="SIGLAPORTAL" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.SIGLAPORTAL}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Comercial</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="COMERCIAL" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.COMERCIAL}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Atendimento</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ATENDIMENTO" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.ATENDIMENTO}}">
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Auditoria</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="AUDITORIA" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.AUDITORIA}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Periodicidade</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="PERIODICIDADE" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.PERIODICIDADE}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Entrega</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ENTREGA" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.ENTREGA}}">
                                  </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Responsável</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="RESPONSAVEL" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.RESPONSAVEL}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Layout</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="LAYOUT" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.LAYOUT}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">DM</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="DM" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.DM}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">ODSDM</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ODSDM" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.ODSDM}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">EFV</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="EFV" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.EFV}}">
                                    </div> 


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Caminho</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="CAMINHO" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.CAMINHO}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Origem</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ORIGEM" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.ORIGEM}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Comercial</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="COMERCIAL" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.COMERCIAL}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Portal</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="PORTAL" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.PORTAL}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">FTP</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="FTP" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.FTP}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Observação</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="OBSERVACAO" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.OBSERVACAO}}">
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Mailing</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="MAILING" value="{{planilhaDetalhes.MAILING}}">
                                     </div> 
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                                      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                        <option>Produção</option>
                                        <option>Other</option>
                                      </select>
                                    </div>
                                    </form>

                </div>
```

Comment: Então ficou bem confusa sua questão, você tem a função **filtrardetalhes()** que não está sendo executada em lugar nenhum.

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de incluir a parte da chamada, editado com ela incluída agora!

Comment: E o que seria **planilha.PID**?

Comment: O ID, este é proveniente do meu INPUT para o NgFor que constrói a tabela inicial (onde o button de detalhes, que abre o modal fica), o filtro está funcional, o problema que estou enfrentando seria na passagem de parâmetros para o meu modal.

Comment: Ao que parece ele filtra depois de abrir o modal, desta forma, o modal só recebe "Object object" da minha variável.

Comment: troque `{{planilhaDetalhes}}` para `{{planilhaDetalhes | json}}`

Comment: Resolvido! Boa Gaspar! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Outra dúvida apenas, consegui passar o | JSON, mas não estou conseguindo passar planilhaDetalhes.CAMPOEXEMPLO | JSON, teria alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia me explicar o funcionamento deste pipe resumidamente "|"?

Comment: O pipe json (| json) é usado para transformar os valores nos campos. Se deseja construir um formulário nessa modal, basta informar `planilhaDetalhes.CAMPOEXEMPLO`no `ngModel` do input deste campo...

Comment: Pipe basicamente é para transformar visualmente um objeto que você não quer alterar ele por completo apenas para mostrar ao usuário na view. A documentação oficial do pipe está [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações a respeito do pipe, será muito útil! Agora a questão do campo, ao colocar {{planilhaDetalhes.PID}} no meu form, o mesmo não retorna nenhum valor. O único jeito que retornou algo foi {{planilhaDetalhes | json}}.

Comment: Incluí o formulário para melhor compreensão

Comment: vou editar minha resposta com as informações necessárias

Comment: Ok! Coloque ela como resposta abaixo e eu terei prazer em votar nela!

Comment: Está editado na resposta! Qualquer duvida me avise

Comment: Existe outra forma sem ser com ngModel? Ao que aparenta alguns recursos do ngModel serão removidos/alterados nas próximas versões do angular, assim, podendo comprometer minha aplicação em caso de atualização.

Comment: Fiz uma gambiarra horrenda com o ngFor chumbado em um json exemplo e funcionou

Comment: O ngModel nunca vai ser removido do angular 2+, pode usar tranquilo. Se tu quiser aplicar um formulário e controlar se está validado ou não, utiliza-se de outro jeito de controlar o estado, porém é o mesmo conceito e não muito recomendado pra quem ta iniciando. Comece usando objetos separados e valide o essencial, quando tudo estiver funcionando, migre os formulários com uma validação mais robusta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi se é o caso, mas acredito que você deseja abrir uma modal em outro componente e não está recebendo os parametros corretamente.

No componente que chama você utiliza esses dados:

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ComponenteModal } from '...';

constructor(private modal: NgbModal) {}

abrirModal(objetoPraPassar: any) {
  const modalRef = this.modal.open(ComponenteModal);
  modalRef.componentInstance.planilhaDetalhes = objetoPraPassar;
}
```

No "ComponenteModal" você faria assim

```
export class ComponenteModal {

  @Input()
  planilhaDetalhes: any;
}
```

EDIT:
Agora que você possui o objeto com os valores construa um formulário no *body* da modal como por exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Descrição</label>
  <input name="descricao" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="entity.descricao" required>
</div>
```

Onde o [ngModel] vai receber os valores digitados e mostrar para o usuário no objeto `entity.descricao`,
o (ngModel) vai atualizar a variável setando `entity.descricao` com os valores digitados,
por isso, utilizado o [(ngModel)] para atualizar e receber os valores.

Em casos que você quer mostrar alguma informação ao usuário que nao seja dentro do ngModel é utilizado duas chaves, como por exemplo `{{ entity.descricao }}`